# Why Mongoid doesn't save boolean as true or false?

Tags: mongoid

I have an app with RoR and Mongoid, and I have a Boolean field in a Document. But when I save the document and see the mongo, it return 0 or 1.

Why mongoid don't save true or false? There's any reason?

I try to find it on documentation of mongoid, but don't have success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True and False values are on the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) as "\x00" and "\x01", as mongoid passes the objects to mongodb using the BSON protocol, true and false are converted to 0 and 1. You can see the code in here https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/master/lib/bson/true_class.rb#L25

Comment: So, if I want to get a boolean I need to do in my model a method that return it? For example: `isLike?`

Comment: Not actually.. your model should return a boolean already. Mongoid should be able to format the 0 and 1 values to false and true..

Comment: Do you know how I do this?? Because I have a field 'like' that is a Boolean, if I type :like it returns 0 or 1